# Next.js overlaps static route with dynamic route

Tags: javascript, reactjs, routes, next.js

I am using Next.JS application routing system.

I have created a dynamic route with structure like `pages/[country]/[language]/index.js`.

Also there is a static route with structure `pages/cz/cz/index.js`.

Issue appears then i am on static page and trying to navigate throught `Link` component to access static route content in my case should go to home page & reload same page, instead of that dynamic route content is rendered.

In my case link is just simple navigation to home page `<Link to="/">` for both routes.
But maybe issue lies on how index.js file is setup for predefined & dynamic routes.

**cz/cz/index.js**

```
export { default } from '../../../components/HomePage/';

const { getStaticProps } = createRoute({
  path: '/',
  locale: 'cs',
});

export { getStaticProps };
```

**[country]/[language]/index.js**

```
export { default } from '../../../components/HomePage/v2';

const { getStaticPaths, getStaticProps } = createRoute({
  path: '/',
  exclude: ['cs'],
  otherLocales: ['cs'],
});

export { getStaticPaths, getStaticProps };
```

**createRoute**

```
export default function createRoute({
  path,
  otherLocales,
  getPathParams,
  locale,
} = {}) {
  const locales = _.without(include, ...exclude);
  return {
    getStaticPaths: createGetStaticPaths({
      locales,
      getPathParams,
    }),
    getStaticProps: createGetStaticProps({
      path,
      locale,
      locales,
      otherLocales,
    }),
  };
}
```

Pages structure

[image]

So why `[country]/[language]/index.js` overrides `cz/cz/index.js` ?

So is there anything available in nextJS route to match a URL absolutely?

Or insure that going from static route should go to static route?

Comment: can you share folder structure and code with link redirection ?

Comment: @FiodorovAndrei added folder structure & updated description

Comment: Are you saying that if you try to access `localhost:3000/cz/cz` in the browser the app renders what's in `pages/[country]/[language]/index.js`?

Comment: @juliomalves accesing from browser it's fine, but going thought Link component, renders `pages/[country]/[language]/index.js` content, actually shoul just reload the page with `localhost:3000/cz/cz` content

Comment: Could you add the code where you're using the `Link` component?

Comment: @juliomalves Link usage is simple `<Link to="/">`, just routing to homepage, which should reload predifined `localhost:3000/cz/cz` route

Comment: What `Link` are you using? You should be using Next.js [built-in `Link`](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next/link) for navigation. Also, what does your homepage look like? Please provide a [mre].

Comment: can't reproduce issue on codesandbox, but provided more code information in description, maybe it helps

Comment: _"routing to homepage, which should reload predifined localhost:3000/cz/cz route"_ - Why is this the case? Without seeing your homepage code it's hard to tell what's wrong.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Following next.js [documentation](https://nextjs.org/docs/routing/dynamic-routes#caveats) predefined routes take precedence over dynamic routes, and dynamic routes over catch all routes.
Take a look at the following examples:

- `pages/post/create.js` - Will match /post/create
- `pages/post/[pid].js` - Will match /post/1, /post/abc, etc. But not /post/create
- `pages/post/[...slug].js` - Will match /post/1/2, /post/a/b/c, etc. But not /post/create, /post/abc

In your case you have defined predefined routes `cz/cz/index.js` and this route have priority

Comment: That's the issue, because my predefined route `cz/cz/index.js`is not taking priority and dynamic route overrides it, vice versa

Comment: You can provide a codesanbox example with you project structure? Because it's hard to understand why dynamic routes overwrite you predefined route.

Comment: can't reproduce issue on codesandbox, but provided more code information in description, maybe it helps

Answer (score 1):

If you happen to be using redirects, note that they are processed before next ever goes to the pages.

> Redirects are checked before the filesystem which includes pages and /public files.

https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next.config.js/redirects